# Proving $\frac{(a_1)^2+(a_2)^2+\cdots+(a_n)^2}{n}\ge \left(\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n}{n}\right)^2 $ for positive real $a_i$

Tags: inequality

> $$\frac{(a_1)^2+(a_2)^2+\cdots+(a_n)^2}{n}\ge \left(\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n}{n}\right)^2 
> $$
> given that $(a_1), (a_2), \ldots, (a_n)$ are positive real numbers

I tried to prove this using AM GM but no luck there, so
I tried to assume a function (then using derivative analysis hoping something happen but nothing).

Can anyone give me a hint????

Comment: This is the AM-RMS inequality, which I tried to find a duplicate for (and I urge others to do so as well). A proof via Cauchy-Schwarz is [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality). If only $AM-GM$ is permissible, consider [this post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) to convert the CS argument into an AM-GM argument.

Comment: this has been asked so many many times!! please search before asking ......

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/536930/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498319/42969.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: This is indeed a multiple duplicate – and I wonder why the top answerer in the [inequality] tag does not recognize that :(

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon Thankyou so much!!!!!!

Comment: @RadacRor Welcome! Please use Approach0 and SearchOnMath to search for mathematical expressions on Math Stackexchange. Doing this will ensure that you don't need to post and wait for answers, they are already here and you can make use of them.

Comment: @MartinR Oh dear, I didn't search with the right terminology. I forgot that the RMS is also called the QM : had I remembered this , I'd have hit the dupe first up. Good spot.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: It suffices to copy/paste the formula into Approach0 and scroll a bit down: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B(a_1)%5E2%2B(a_2)%5E2%2B%5Ccdots%2B(a_n)%5E2%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cge%20%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Ba_1%2Ba_2%2Ba_3%2B%5Ccdots%2Ba_n%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%5E2%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MartinR Correct : I narrowed my search heavily because on every such occasion that I searched, AM-RMS was a keyword. That's why I missed the above duplicate. I'll be careful next time!

Comment: Thankyou All of you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2}{n}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n1^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2}{n^2}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2}{n^2}=\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i}{n}\right)^2.$$
Another way:

It's just Jensen for the convex function $f(x)=x^2.$

Another way:
$$n\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)^2=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(a_i-a_j)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Come on, this has been asked and answered many times. (Even you answered it before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2246332/42969.)